# jq parsing json input with variables

Tags: json, jq

I have this input:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "tester-01",
      "user": {
        "username": "tester01"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "tester-02",
      "user": {
        "username": "tester02"
      }
    }
  ],
  "current-user": "tester-02"
}
```

Using jq (1.5), I want to print the username that matches current-user.

Can anyone share how this would be done or tips to get me started?

Comment: I've come up with:

jq -r '."current-user" as $foo | .users[] | select(.name == $foo).user'

are there alternatives?

Comment: This is probably more on-topic for codereview.stackexchange.com, but I think you'll need to be more specific about what you think could be improved

Comment: @user3694539 Yours appears to be the canonical solution to this problem. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution.

```
cat 99 | jq -r '."current-user" as $foo | .users[] | select(.name == $foo).user'
{
  "username": "tester02"
}
```

Comment: `-r` isn't needed, since you are outputing a JSON object, not a string value.

Answer (score 0):

The **select** solution is good.  Here is an alternative that uses **foreach**.

```
foreach .users[] as $u (
     ."current-user"
   ; .
   ; if . == $u.name then $u.user.username else empty end
)
```